# How to interpret covariate balance table for binary variables in inverse probability treatment weighting

Tags: propensity-scores, matching

A quick question on how to interpret balance measures in a IPTW analysis.
Here is an example code from the `cobalt` package:

```
require("WeightIt")
require("cobalt")
data("lalonde", package = "cobalt") #If not yet loaded
covs <- subset(lalonde, select = -c(treat, re78, nodegree, married))

#Generating propensity score weights for the ATT
W.out <- weightit(treat ~ covs, data = lalonde,
                  method = "ps", estimand = "ATT")

bal.tab(W.out)
```

And here is the output:

```
Call
 weightit(formula = treat ~ covs, data = lalonde, method = "ps", 
    estimand = "ATT")

Balance Measures
                Type Diff.Adj
prop.score  Distance  -0.0397
age          Contin.   0.1112
educ         Contin.  -0.0641
race_black    Binary  -0.0044
race_hispan   Binary   0.0016
race_white    Binary   0.0028
re74         Contin.  -0.0039
re75         Contin.  -0.0428

Effective sample sizes
           Control Treated
Unadjusted   429.      185
Adjusted     108.2     185
```

Now, the question is: what does `Diff.Adj` means for binary covariates? While I am able to interpret this measure for continuous variable (i.e., the standardize mean difference between the two groups after adjustment), I am having an hard time interpreting this when relating to binary variables. What does this means?

Comment: As a side note any time one examines balance with respect to only a single measure of central tendency (such as the mean) one ignores potentially important imbalances not reflected in the mean, e.g., an imbalance of 0.95 quantiles where there is a lot of action on the outcome (sharp risk increase).

Comment: @FrankHarrell yes, I get this point, and would have been extremely useful to know whether are there some other methods to evaluate post-weighting balance between covariates...

Comment: Did you bother reading the [documentation](https://ngreifer.github.io/cobalt/reference/bal.tab.html)? It is explained very clearly there. And there are many options available to summarize balance, including several measures that account for imbalance in the whole distribution.

Comment: Great.  I assume Kolmogorov-Smirnov is used for whole distribution.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Yes, and the [overlapping coefficient](http://doi.wiley.com/10.1002/sim.6058) (area of the overlap between the covariate densities) is also available.